# Azure container instnaces not able to reach key vault

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-container-instances

Azure container instances behave differently to local Docker containers. When getting secret from Azure Key Vault via secret identifier I receive:

`Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved`

However when running locally this does not happen and instead it is able to get the secret without issue.

Comment: Do you mean pull image from a registry with the secret in yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Is it Windows container? There is a known issue that it requires a couple seconds to have outbound network for ACI Windows container. The recommendation is to add some retry logic for any outbound requests.